# Input Dialog without icon and only OK option

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm trying to make a JOptionPane with input area that only has an OK button.

When trying to do this, there is no icon but an additional cancel button:

```
String name = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name", "Name required", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, "name");
```

And when I do this there's an icon:

```
String name = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name", "Name required", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, null, null, "name");
```

Is there a way to combine the two? I don't understand how the latter works because I used null where you'd place an icon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
JTextField field  = new JTextField(20);
JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter your text here");
JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 2));
p.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);
p.add(field);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p, "Name required", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null);
String text = field.getText();
System.out.println("You've entered: " + text);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, does this mean there's no build in thing for it? Why is the null parameter for icon ignored when choosing OK_OPTION?

Comment: And is it also possible to combine this with a showInputDialog instead of showMessageDialog?

Comment: Thanks for the extra documentations